# curl -d "123" : The string data has equal symbol attached to it

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a POST API in spring boot Restcontroller which accepts a string and returns back the string. But the recieved string value has special characters as "="

```
@RestController
public class MyApi{
    @PostMapping(path = "/", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
    public String parseInput(@RequestBody String data)    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

`curl -d "1" http://localhost:1337/` gives `1=` instead of `1`

Comment: May I know how to remove padding character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-url-encoded-form-data#1-formhttpmessageconverter-basics

**This helped me :**

```
@PostMapping(
  path = "/feedback",
  consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<String> handleNonBrowserSubmissions(
  @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> paramMap) throws Exception {
    // Save feedback data
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Thank you for submitting feedback", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I just had to change the data type in the method argument to "`@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> paramMap`"

---

So when I do `curl -d '1' http://localhost:1337/` , I had to extract the key separately like this :

```
String data = (String) ((Map.Entry) paramMap.entrySet().toArray()[0]).getKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `-d "1"` with `curl`, you try to:

> [send] the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This  will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

This essentially means that the payload is treated as key-value pairs separated by an ampersand (&) character, while key and value are separated with the equals sign (=).

In your case, `1` is treated as the key and its value is missing, hence the `1=` you receive.

If you want to only consume plain text, you need to:

1. Change `consumes = {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN}`
2. Use `curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset: utf-8" -d "1" ...`

Comment: May I know how to fix the above API and make it work as expected?

Comment: Is it possible to do without change in curl command? Because APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE is the format for RequestBody.